# Code optimization python loops

Tags: python, performance, loops

My code looks like this:

```
if query.orderby:
    for q in query.orderby:
        if 'severity' in q:
```

Note: query.orderby is a list of dict. Looks something like
[{"severity": "asc"},{"name": "desc"}] 
How can i optimize these lines? Is there any way to replace the for loop and still get same functionality as the code above?

Comment: what logic in if statement?

Comment: [What does "list comprehension" in Python mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34835951)

Comment: It depends on what you want to do after last `if`.

Comment: Basically if the key 'severity' is present, i alter its value and sort the array items based on the key value

Comment: You wrote "query.orderby is a list of dict".  If `query` always has an attribute `.orderby` then your first `if` (`if query.orderby:`) is superflous.  Otherwise, your `for` loop followed by an `if` is, at least in my opinion, as good as a more complex solution that iterates on a filtered version of `query.orderby`, e.g., `for q in (q in query.orderby if 'severity' in q)` — your present implementation (modulo the first `if`, that could be removed) adds a level of indentation but expresses in a more clean way your purpose

Comment: Thanks @gboffi. orderby need not be present always.That's the reason ive added the first `if` clause

Comment: OK, so your code is as good as it can be...

Comment: @gboffi thanks for the help.

Comment: @sanjana I think you can remove your first if statement.

Comment: I've changed my mind, if the `orderby` attribute is optional, you have a problem with a bare `if`... see my answer below. Ciao

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give you optimisation without understanding what's going on in `if condition` however if result of that loop is list - you can use [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk):

```
# ensure query.order_by is iterable
query.order_by = query.orderby if geattr(query, 'orderby', None) else []
result = [ item for item in query.order_by if 'severity' in item]
```

Another good choice is to filter items prior iterating over them:

```
query.order_by = query.orderby if geattr(query, 'orderby', None) else []
for item in filter(lambda x: 'severity' in x, items):
    print item['severity']
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
filtered = [q for q in query.orderby if 'severity' in q]
```

would filter into a new list

Answer (score 1):

If query.orderby is a list of dict than you should go like that:

```
x = [{"severity": "asc"}, {"name": "desc"}]

for e in x:
    for key, value in e.iteritems():
        if 'severity' in key:
            print 'yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial statement

```
if query.orderby:
```

in light of [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721252/code-optimization-python-loops?noredirect=1#comment62915422_37721252) to a comment of mine

> `orderby` need not be present always

is not what you want... look at this interactive session

```
In [1]: class Query(): pass

In [2]: query = Query()

In [3]: query.orderfrom = 1

In [4]: if query.orderfrom: print(1)
1

In [5]: if query.orderby: print(1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-27f5f9b9569b> in <module>()
----> 1 if query.orderby: print(1)

AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'orderby'

In [6]:
```

My recommends are either a `try` ... `except` clause

```
try:
    orderby = query.orderby
except AttributeError:
    orderby = []

for q in orderby:
    if 'severity' in q:
        ...
```

or a solution based on `getattr()`, as proposed by Andriy Ivaneyko, but simpler

```
 # use getattr to have the attribute OR a convenient, here [], default.
 orderby = getattr(query, 'orderby', [])

 for q in orderby:
     if 'severity' in q:
         ...
```